# How to post to remote url on form submit

Tags: forms

We want to silently submit a Drupal6 form to a marketing partner, and redirect the user to page on our site.  Is this the correct syntax?

```
function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['action'] = url('http://example.com/?method=cSurveyWebservice.submit&mode=test');
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('campaign/thank-you');
}
```

Certainly it processes and redirects, although I'm not sure how to independently validate if the form is actually posted to the specified URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
$request_url = 'http://your-url.com';
$request_headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$request_method = 'POST';
$request_retry = 2;
// form values you want to post
$form_values= array('apple' => 'red', 'banana' => 'yellow', 'pear' => 'green');
$data = http_build_query($fruits, '', '&');

// Send the request.
$response = drupal_http_request($request_url, $request_headers, $request_method, $data, $request_retry);

if ($response->code == 200) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('campaign/thank-you');
}
else {
drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem with your submission. Please try again later.'), 'error');
}
```

I haven't tried it but let me know if it works.

Comment: very nice, thanks.  I implemented in a submit handler, and added the following to include the form elements in the request:   '$skip_keys = array('submit', 'form_build_id', 'form_id');
  foreach ($form_state['values'] as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, $skip_keys)) { 
     $form_values[$key] = $value;
    }'

Comment: @August1914 glad to hear it worked.